# UIViewController being pushed down on screen when displayed using insertSubview

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, xcode4

Having a bit of a problem, here's the breakdown:

My AppDelegate uses as it's rootViewController a view controller. This view controller's purpose is to swap a couple of other view controllers in and out, call it login and main screens. For the sake of simplicity I've removed any swapping code from the code that I will post and am having the rootViewController simply show it's first content view controller, say login.

The issue I'm having is that the content view controller seems to be pushed down a little bit inside the rootViewController. I've given the rootViewController a blue background and the content view controller an orange background. Here's my code:

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class MainViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) MainViewController *main;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize main;

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_window release];
    [main release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    MainViewController *mainVC = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
    self.main = mainVC;
    self.window.rootViewController = self.main;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

MainViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ContentViewController;

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, retain) ContentViewController *content;

@end
```

MainViewController.m

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "ContentViewController.h"

@implementation MainViewController

@synthesize content;

- (id)init
{
self = [super init];
    if (self ) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    ContentViewController *viewController = [[ContentViewController alloc] init];
    self.content = viewController;
    [self.view insertSubview:self.content.view atIndex:0];              
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [content release];  
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

ContentViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LoginVC : UIViewController

@end
```

ContentViewController.m

```
#import "ContentViewController.h"

@implementation ContentViewController

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

The above codes gives me a status bar with a blue strip (approximately the height of the status bar) under it (which is the main view controller) followed by the orange content view controller taking up the rest of the screen. For some reason that main view controller seems to be pushing the content view controller down a little.

Strangely, if I create a view controller and use a XIB for drawing the view, it looks just fine and the content view it right up against the top of the main view.

If anybody could shed some light on this issue I'd very much appreciate it.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that you shouldn't be doing

```
ContentViewController *viewController = [[ContentViewController alloc] init];
self.content = viewController;
[self.view insertSubview:self.content.view atIndex:0];
```

but rather:

```
ContentViewController *viewController = [[ContentViewController alloc] init];
self.content = viewController;
[self presentViewController:self.content animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Afraid that didn't work, now I don't see the content view controller (orange) at all. I ended up with a warning: "Warning: Attempt to present <ContentViewController: 0x804f4f0> on <MainViewController: 0x804d200> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"

Looking into possible reasons for this.

Comment: This warning happens because you're calling 'presentViewController...' inside the "viewDidLoad" method. To get rid of the warning call 'presentViewController...' inside the "viewDidAppear:" method instead.
However, I was trying to reproduce your original problem but I'm not getting the same behavior you described. Are you hiding the status bar?

Comment: Yep, calling the above code from viewDidAppear does the trick, tested it.
Whatever other custom method you would like to call it from will be fine too, in case that method is not called from viewDidLoad.

Comment: You could call 'presentModalViewController:animated:' inside viewDidLoad and the application won't crash indeed, however that method is deprecated. Now we have to use 'presentViewController:animated:completion:' and calling that method inside viewDidLoad will cause the application to crash.

Comment: Calling 'presentViewController:animated:completion' in the viewDidAppear method did the trick as far as showing the first content view controller. Thanks for that.

New issue however.... removing that first content view controller and replacing it with different one. '[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:NULL]' does nothing. Also tried '[self.content.view removeFromSuperview]' which turns the screen black so I'm assuming it removes not only the content view controller (orange background) but also the rootViewController (blue background)?

Comment: Probably the same problem once again: calling [self dismissViewControllerAnimated: completion:] from ContentViewController's viewDidAppear method does the job and removes itself

Comment: And I think you should forget about trying to manipulate ViewController's base views like: [self.view removeFromSuperview] or [self.view addSubview someViewController.view] that is not only a bad practice, it will lead you nowhere most of the times